# Compare Two Worksheets and Copy Row Data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare two worksheets in one workbook. Some *pseudocode*:

> If Cell A on Worksheet1 = Cell A on Worksheet2 And 
>  If Cell F on
>   Worksheet1 <> Cell F on Worksheet2 Then 
>  Copy Row from Worksheet2
>   over the Row on Worksheet1 Else 
>  If Cell A on Worksheet1 <> Cell A
>   on Worksheet2 Then 
>  Copy Row from Worksheet2 to next blank Row on
>   Worksheet1

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub CopyCells()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim j As Long, i As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long


Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastrow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1
    For j = 1 To lastrow2
        If sh1.Cells(i, "A").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "A").Value And sh1.Cells(i, "F").Value <> sh2.Cells(j, "F").Value Then
            sh1.Cells(i, "F").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "F").Value
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you be clear in your question what the *specific* problem is? e.g. code does not work, there is a code error etc...

Comment: I am getting a mismatch error, and I am not able to figure out the portion of copying over the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyCells()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, counter As Long

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lastrow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    counter = 1

    For i = 1 To lastrow1
        For j = 1 To lastrow2
            If sh1.Range("A" & i) = sh2.Range("A" & j) And sh1.Range("F" & i) <> sh2.Range("F" & j) Then
                sh2.Range("A" & j).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh1.Range("A" & i)
            ElseIf sh1.Range("A" & i) <> sh2.Range("A" & j) Then
                sh2.Range("A" & j).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh1.Range("A" & lastrow1 + counter)
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this starts to run for a minute, and then I get a Type Mismatch Error. When I debug this portion is highlighted: <br>

Comment: If sh1.Range("A" & i) = sh2.Range("A" & j) And sh1.Range("F" & i) <> sh2.Range("F" & j) Then

Comment: Shouldnt it be something like If sh1.Range("A" & i).Value = sh2.Range("A" & j).Value And sh1.Range("F" & i).Value = sh2.Range("F" & j).Value Then?

Comment: So Cell A would have something like x12345678 and Cell F would have Finalized. There would be no variance outside of strings in Cell F and Cell A would always contain a letter and several integers.